# Obtener el value de un input range e imprimirlo en un div en Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Quiero lograr que cada vez que se cambie el valor del **input** tipo **range**, se coloque el value en el div, lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

> formulario.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-auto mt-4">
   <label class="mr-4">Porcentaje<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
   <div class="box">
      <div id="value"></div>
   </div>
   <input id="slider" class="slider" (change)="value()" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
</div>
```

> formulario.component.ts

```
value() {
   var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
   var val = document.getElementById('value');
   console.log(slider);
   console.log(val);
}
```

Por el momento solo estoy imprimiendo ambos elementos en consola, pero cuando coloco dentro del formulario.component.ts lo siguiente:

```
value() {
   var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
   var val = document.getElementById('value');
   val.innerHTML = slider.value;
}
```

Me aparece el error "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)" y no sé cómo lograrlo, agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que TypeScript es fuertemente tipado. Por esa razón, `document.getElementById('slider')` regresa un objeto del tipo `HTMLElement`, el cuál no contiene la propiedad value. En cambio, `HTMLInputElement` sí la contiene, así que se tiene que hacer la conversión:

```
var slider =<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('slider');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó, no tenía idea c: